# A plugin doesn't show up and refuse to be installed

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to install the SEO by Yoast plugin.

My WordPress is host on DigitalOcean (previously host on OVH) and is located in /var/www/. When I check inside /var/www/wp-content/plugins/, there is no wordpress-seo folder.

In my dashboard, when I install the plugin, WordPress displays:

```
Installing the plugin…
Destination folder already exists. /homez.722/culturesc/www/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/
```

What is interesting is that I have no /homez.722/culturesc/ folder on my server (I can't find it). It seems that Wordpress is not installing the plugin in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/ and that is probably the reason why when I manually upload wordpress-seo inside the plugin directory it doesn't show up on my dashboard.

What is happening?

Comment: Did you try to install manually by uploading the files via FTP?

Comment: Yes that's what I did via Filezilla.

Comment: `/homez.722/culturesc/` seems like the path in the server to your hosting account, so you don't have that folder because you are already inside that folder and you can't go to higher levels.

Comment: A quick search engine check shows `/homez.722/` is from OVH. Did you check your database for paths since you moved to the droplet? Was the plugin installed previously?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a symptom of the problem of a failed install.
If you look at that actual folder on the server it'll probably be a couple folders, but no php files and a bunch of missing files that are in the plugin zip.

Maybe something failing on unzip, or ftp, caused half-installed state of not having the main php file. There are long-standing bugs in WP that might be related to this: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29610

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to avoid this error is to delete your existing themes and plugins. I was facing the same problem for about 2 months and finally decided to deleted the themes and plugins and it worked fine for me.